# Permission_required decorator not working on view in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-permissions

I have an model called client, and a group called managers that has the permission "can view clients" granted in Django admin.

I have a view using the permission_required decorator like so:

```
@permission_required('client.view_client', raise_exception=True)
```

Originally I had it as

```
@permission_required('client.can_view', raise_exception=True)
```

which also fails.

When logged in as a user who is a member of group managers, I am unable to access the view as I get a `403 Forbidden` message.

Why is this? If the user is a member of the group with the appropriate permission, why is access not authorized?

Comment: `'<app label>.<permission codename>'` (e.g. polls.can_vote for the can_vote permission on a model in the polls *application*. You need to specify the app's name, not the model's name

Comment: @Pynchia That's actually what I had it as originally. I had it set as `client.can_view` but I changed it as while searching I thought the way I have it now was correct. Either way results in a forbidden error.

Comment: Is your view a function or a CBV?

Comment: @Pynchia function